# Sitecore global find and replace path?

Tags: sitecore

Is there a way to globally replace a path to an item which has moved? For instance, if I have a module located at home/moldule/oldlocation and I move it to home/module/newlocation but, I know the oldlocation is used in 100 places, can I essentially do a find a replace?

Comment: I realise this isn't much help in your current situation, but it is usually recommended that where possible you should reference items by GUID rather than path for this very reason. See John West's Blog article on Accessing Items in Sitecore: 


http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/04/Accessing-Items-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx

Comment: When you navigate through the UI to add/link a new module it defaults to linking the path... is there anyway to navigate the tree UI and have it use the GUID when clicking an item rather than the path to it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the item is being referenced. If those 100+ places reference it as an internal link (from within the WYSIWYG editor), or in reference fields (Treelist, Droplink, Droptree, etc.), then you don't have to find and replace anything. When using these types of links, Sitecore stores the item's GUID, and therefore the paths will be automatically updated when you move the target item.

There are a few cases in which you would need to update the paths, such as using a non-reference based field type (such as a Droplist), an external link entered into the WYSIWYG editor, or in a presentation component's Datasource field. In these cases, you can use the [Search and Replace](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Search_and_Replace.aspx) module and/or [Sitecore Rocks](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/44a26c88-83a7-46f6-903c-5c59bcd3d35b) to handle the searching and replacing.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at using Sitecore  Rocks Search and Replace functionality. You can refine the fields and templates to make the search really targeted.

There are some more details here
http://www.sitecore.net/unitedkingdom/Community/Technical-Blogs/Trevor-Campbell/Posts/2013/02/28-Days-of-Sitecore-Rocks-Hidden-Gems-Part-2.aspx